# scroll-target="document" from within custom element with iron-scroll-threshold

Tags: scroll, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I want to fire an method of a nested custom element when the document scroll position gets close to the bottom using iron-scroll-threshold.

So, I have an the index.html file like this:

```
 <link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">
 <body>
  <my-app></my-app>
 </body>
</html>
```

and inside the my-app element, I have my-questions element like this:

```
        <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <my-questions name="questions"></my-questions>
      <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
    </iron-pages>
```

Now finally inside the my-questions element, I have

```
<ul id="question-list">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[questions]]" sort="_computeSort" as="question">
      <poll-result questionkey="[[question.$key]]"></poll-result>
    </template>
</ul>
<iron-scroll-threshold on-lower-threshold="_loadMoreQuestions" lower-threshold="400" id="threshold" lower-triggered="{{nearBottom}}" scroll-target="document">
</iron-scroll-threshold>
```

and my loadMoreQuestions function:

```
_loadMoreQuestions: function(){
  console.log('load more questions fired');
  var questionCount = this.$.questionQuery.limitToLast;
  this.$.questionQuery.limitToLast = questionCount + 10;
  var threshold=this.$.threshold;
  threshold.clearTriggers();
},
```

Now, the _loadMoreQuestions method fires once when the page is loaded, but never again. How can I made this method to fire whenever the document is scrolled 400px from the bottom?